# Why GraphQL is not detecting a new field in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, gatsby

I'm new in Gatsby Development, in my website I'm using a community theme and modifying it in some things.

My problem started when I modified a JSON file called 'settings.json', where **I added a field** in the **siteConfiguration** object, the original file was this:

```
{"siteConfiguration": {
    "logo": { "text": "chrisley"},
    "navigation": {
      "header": [
        { "label": "About", "url": "/#about" },
        { "label": "Blog", "url": "/blog" },
        { "label": "Features", "url": "/#features" },
        { "label": "Github", "url": "/#github" }
      ],
      "ctaButton": {
        "openNewTab": true,
        "label": "Resume",
        "url": "/resume.pdf"
      },
      "footer": [
        { "label": "Privacy", "url": "/privacy" },
        { "label": "Imprint", "url": "/imprint" }
      ]
    },
    "featureToggles": {
      "useDarkModeAsDefault": false,
      "useDarkModeBasedOnUsersPreference": true,
      "useCookieBar": false
    }
  }
}
```

And the one where I added the field 'img' inside "logo" is the following:

```
{"siteConfiguration": {
    "logo": { "text": "chrisley","img":"/content/images/logo-dark.png"},
    "navigation": {
      "header": [
        { "label": "About", "url": "/#about" },
        { "label": "Blog", "url": "/blog" },
        { "label": "Features", "url": "/#features" },
        { "label": "Github", "url": "/#github" }
      ],
      "ctaButton": {
        "openNewTab": true,
        "label": "Resume",
        "url": "/resume.pdf"
      },
      "footer": [
        { "label": "Privacy", "url": "/privacy" },
        { "label": "Imprint", "url": "/imprint" }
      ]
    },
    "featureToggles": {
      "useDarkModeAsDefault": false,
      "useDarkModeBasedOnUsersPreference": true,
      "useCookieBar": false
    }
  }
}
```

And when I trying to get the `img` field in GraphQL with this Query:

```
query SiteConfiguration {
  allSettingsJson: allContentJson {
    settings: nodes {
      siteConfiguration {
        logo {
          text
          img
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the next error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"img\" on type \"Logo\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 7,
          "column": 11
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "stack": [
          "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"img\" on type \"Logo\".",
          "    at Object.Field (/Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Gatsby/chrisley_dev_website/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectTypeRule.js:48:31)",
          "    at Object.enter (/Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Gatsby/chrisley_dev_website/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)",
          "    at Object.enter (/Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Gatsby/chrisley_dev_website/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
          "    at visit (/Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Gatsby/chrisley_dev_website/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)",
          "    at validate (/Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Gatsby/chrisley_dev_website/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)",
          "    at graphqlMiddleware (/Users/chrisley/Documents/Development/Gatsby/chrisley_dev_website/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js:98:38)",
          "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope you can help me guys, as always haha

Comment: How are you implementing your `settings.json`? Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be answering myself because I found the problem hahaha.

The problem was that I was missing updating the Schema of the theme, in particular of this theme was the file `gastby/node/createSchemaCustomization.js`

So.. after updating the file with this lines:

```
module.exports = ({ actions }) => {
    actions.createTypes(`
    ...
    type Logo {
        text: String
        img: String
    }
    ...
  `);
};
```

GraphQL detected my new field 'img' of the 'logo' object.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I'm assuming you are using the following starter: https://github.com/konstantinmuenster/gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal/tree/main/gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal

Have you tried stopping your development process and cleaning Gatsby cache by:

```
gatsby clean
```

Or manually deleting the `.cache` folder.

Comment: Hi!
Yes I used gatsby clean and the problem remains. And also yes, I'm using that theme haha.